# Scam Potential: Images of receipts sent over email

Tags: scams

A friend of mine just got a bunch of images of receipts sent to him from India.  They were unsolicited, random images with no text.  Here's one:

[image]

Anybody seen anything like this, how could it be a scam?

Comment: Just a bunch of images, sent randomly to your friend in an unsolicited e-mail message from someone he doesn't know?  Any text in the message to go along with the attachments?

Comment: looks like a simple misspelling in the email address. But then, some image formats allow to embed code that gets executed when they get opened...

Comment: @BenMiller No text, just random images of receipts.

Comment: What is stopping him from throwing these in the trash?  If its a scam, its pretty lame.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With no explanation and no call to action, I can't see how these could be used in a scam.  I agree with Aganju in the comments: Your friend most likely mistakenly received a message intended for someone else due to a typo in the e-mail address.

If he's feeling helpful, he could reply to let the sender know of the mistake, but the sender will probably figure it out on his own before too long.  Delete the message and don't worry about it.